# Proxy Issues: automatic configuration script (http://127.0.0.1:8080/proxy.pac )

Tags: proxy, fiddler, pac

I have been using "Hola Better Internet" (proxy plugin) on chrome for long time.

Recently I had lot of problems with it. Google search is not working properly and it also not let me to sign in to gmail. yahoo  and bing works well.

When I check proxy seeting on chrome, use automatic configuration script is enabled (cant able to deactivate it). It points to the following address:

127.0.0.1:8080/proxy.pac

When I visit the above url, the following script got downloaded.

// Autogenerated file; do not edit. Rewritten on attach and detach of Fiddler.

function FindProxyForURL(url, host){
  if (shExpMatch(host, "www.google.*")) return "PROXY 127.0.0.1:8080"; return "DIRECT";
}

I am not a programmer. I googled a lot to find a solution, but i cant understand anything. Please help guys.

Comment: This question belongs on SuperUser or similar. You probably have malware running on your PC (e.g. BrowserSafeguard or similar). You can use `netstat -o -a` to see what process is listening on port `8080` to track the culprit down and remove it.

Comment: I found a solution here: [link](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/561908/can-able-to-change-my-proxy-settings-in-internet-options)